# [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: Error code 0x2746

Tags: php, sql-server, ubuntu, odbc

I try to connect to a database from an ubuntu 20.04 server, my connexion works from an older server on ubuntu 18.04 and is not working on the new one.
i have this error: `[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: Error code 0x2746`.
I try to connect to an sql 2005 sever.

On old server I have `OpenSsl 1.1.1` and on the new one `1.1.1f`
On old server i have `[ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]`
and on the new one `[ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server] [ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]`

I tried to do `openssl s_client -connect IP:PORT -tls1`
and I get `CONNECTED(00000003)`
My php line to connect is
`new PDO ("sqlsrv:Server=$hostname,$port;Database=$dbname;TrustServerCertificate=Yes;Encrypt=no", "$username", "$pw");`

Comment: Can you post the whole error message instead of just the error code?

Comment: I only have that message: `SQLSTATE[08001]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: Error code 0x2746`

Comment: ODBC Driver 17 does not support SQL Server 2005. The "newest" version that does is ODBC 11. See the [support matrix](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/windows/system-requirements-installation-and-driver-files?view=sql-server-ver16#sql-version-compatibility). TL;DR: it's long past time you upgrade your SQL Server.

Comment: As a note the *only* Linux operating system that ODBC 11 was available on was a Preview version of the driver on SUSE Enterprise 11. Support for Ubuntu was not added until ODBC 13.

Comment: Tank you for this I didn't look at this matrix I will try to install ODBC 11 instead of 17

Comment: You won't be able to, @thibaultdufour , there was no ODBC 11 on Ubuntu. You'll need to use a different driver. Though, again, what you really should be doing is updating to a version of SQL Server that is supported; support for 2005 completed ended 7/8 years ago.

Comment: Is there any other drivers availables on ubuntu 20.04 to connect to a sql server 2005 ? 
Otherwise, i will try to update the version of my sql server

Comment: try FreeTDS perhaps?